# A Rather Odd Who Am I?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge, acrostic

Tried something new with this. Hopefully it pans out well. I don't expect it to be too difficult... Good Luck!

So who am I?

> Riddling never
>
> I'm going
>
> Crazy to
>
> Kindly give
>
> Receptive you
>
> Onward up
>
> Lies never
>
> Loudly let
>
> Even you
>
> Drive down

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well,

> The first letters spell RICKROLLED

and

> The second word in every phrase spells out the famous lyrics to "Never Going To Give You Up" by Rick Astley.

So I'd say you are

> <s>Rick Astley</s> some internet troll!

Comment: +1 for the 'correction' in the "So I'd say you are ..." section.

Comment: Correct with both answers

Answer (score 1):

Found a great video on how to solve this puzzle ;)

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ